# Is there an AI assistant that can observe and control my computer/cell phone

Tags: intelligent-personal-assistants

I do a lot of boring office work, mostly on various websites, lots of copy and pasting and entering data into spreadsheets, making contracts, sending the same boiler plate emails to clients, making invoices and following up.

It seems like AI would be able to do most of my job after observing me for a few weeks or months.

Are there any programs that can basically take over my computer/phone, observe me, and then complete tasks for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Asking for software or tools is off-topic here. We focus on the theoretical, social and philosophical aspects of AI. You could try asking this question on Software Recommendations SE or Data Science SE.

Comment: The question could be changed to whether such an agent is feasible by combining existing models available to the public, and that could make it more on topic.

Comment: We are not yet at the point where you can describe by word what you want and the AI does that, but we are getting close for popular websites